# Is there a way to make external fixed layout iframe child page to work on mobile?

Tags: javascript, css, iframe, responsive-design, drupal-7

I'm working on a mobile site running Drupal.

The goal is to embed a third-party calendar software into the page. The calendar I'm trying to embed just happens to be fixed-width.

The following css makes the iframe and any responsive content inside of it work nicely, but where I ran against the wall was the fixed-width child page.

```css
.embed-container {
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 56.25%; /* 16/9 ratio */
    padding-top: 30px; /* IE6 workaround*/
    height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.embed-container iframe,
.embed-container object,
.embed-container embed {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

I put some thought into responsiveiframe.js, but that seems to include a script for the third-party child page, so are there any other ways to make it "responsive"/work on mobile?

Answer (score 0):

For a exact answer i will need more information about the elements.
but try this `width:100% !important;` for overwrite :)